# Input type=range. how do i make the slider values divisible by 10?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day,

```
<input type="range" min="0" max"500" value="0" id="slider">
```

based on the html above, is it possible to make the slider values divisible by 10?
For example when the user drags the slider.. values will go up from 0 - 10 - 20 - 30. instead of the default 1,2,3,4,5......

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the [step attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```html
   <input type="range" max="500" min="0" step="10" id="slider" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the step attribute.

```html
   <input type="range" min="0" max"500" value="0" step="10" id="slider">
```

Be aware that this is only supported from IE10 and later.

Comment: [Please don't link to or recommend w3schools.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max "500" value="0" step="10" id="slider">
```

[For more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range)

Answer (score -1):

Add step attribute

```
<input type="range" min="0" max"500" value="0" step="50" id="slider">
```

The stepping interval, used both for user interface and validation purposes

Comment: Aside from your answer being very low quality, it doesn’t even give the OP an example. Please edit your answer accordingly.